# Animation on Hidden Elements to Visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, element

On my project when you choose chair (first option) or table(second option) it appears on the right side. What I want to do is I just want to add some effects on chair's or table's appearing. It comes with my click via checkbox. Maybe some fading or scaling animation. Is it possible to add one more function on it ? Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Demo Link
https://vigilant-allen-a37d54.netlify.app/

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
    display: none;
  }
  
  label {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
    
  }






  .container {

 

    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #707070;
    z-index: 12;

  }


  .container h1 {

    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 25px;

  }

  .container p {

    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 18px;

  }

  input:focus,
  select:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

  .button {
    background-color:  #4b4b4b;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 62px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
   
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 1px solid #4b4b4b;
      border-radius: 21px;
  }

  .button1:hover {
    background-color: #757575;
    color: white;
  }


  
  label::before {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  
  label img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  
  :checked+label {
    border-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  :checked+label::before {
    content: "✓";
    background-color: grey;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  :checked+label img {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  
    z-index: -1;
  }


.render {
  display:block;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index:-2;
  left: 0; 
  bottom:0;
}

.render2 {
  display:block;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index:-2;
  left: 0; 
  bottom:0;
}

.render3 {
  display:block;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index:-2;
  left: 0; 
  bottom:0;
}

  #render {
  
    visibility: hidden
  }


  #render2 {
  
    visibility: hidden
  }

  #render3 {
  
    visibility: hidden
  }

  #render4 {
  
    visibility: hidden
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.js" />
 
    <title>Dc Works Demo</title>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(function () {
   
    var url = "https://vigilant-allen-a37d54.netlify.app/";

    var choice = [];

    $("input:button[value='EVİNİZİ 3D-AR İLE GÖRÜNTÜLEYİN']").click(function () {
 
        $("input:checkbox[name^='choice']:checked").each(function (i, el) {
  
            choice += "choice=" + $(el).attr('name') + "&";
        });
      
        choice = choice.slice(0, -1);
      
        $('form').attr("action", url + choice).submit();
    });
 });
 </script>

 <style>

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("bosevkucuk.png");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <br>
    <div class="container">
    <ul>
      
     <P>DC WORKS DEMO <BR> 3D GÖRÜNTÜLEME <BR>ARTIRILMIŞ GERÇEKLİK</P>
      <br>
       <h1>Evinde İstediğin Eşyaları Seç</h1>
       
            <br><br>

        <form name="search_something" action="" method="get">


        <li><input onclick="myFunction()" type="checkbox" name="choice1" id="cb1" />
          <label for="cb1"><img src="sandalye3-01.png" /></label>
          <center><p>Gri Tekli Sandalye</p></center>
        </li>

        <li><input onclick="myFunction2()" type="checkbox" name="choice2" id="cb2" />
          <label for="cb2"><img src="masa3-01.png" /> </label>
          <center><p>Köşe masa</p></center>
        </li>

        <li><input onclick="myFunction3()" type="checkbox" name="choice3" id="cb3" />
          <label for="cb3"><img src="hali3-01.png" /></label>
          <center><p>El İşlemesi Halı</p></center>
        </li>

  
        
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input class="button button1" type="button" value="EVİNİZİ 3D-AR İLE GÖRÜNTÜLEYİN">
    </form>
 </center>
      </ul>
 </div>


 <br><br>
<center>
 <div >
 <img class="render" id="render" src="sandalyeson.png" />
 <img class="render2"id="render2" src="masason.png" />
 <img class="render3" id="render3" src="hali.png" />

 </div>
 </center>


 <script>
   function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('render');
   if (x.style.visibility === 'visible') {
    x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   } else {
    x.style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
   }
 </script>

  
  <script>
   function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById('render2');
    if (x.style.visibility === 'visible') {
      x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
      x.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    }
  </script>

  

 <script>
  function myFunction3() {
  var x = document.getElementById('render3');
  if (x.style.visibility === 'visible') {
   x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
   x.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
  }
 </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transition property to give effects like fade-in, fade-out, etc.

In style CSS :

```
#render{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1000ms linear 0ms;
}
```

And your myFunction will look like :

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('render');
   if (x.style.opacity == '0') {
      x.style.opacity = '1';
   } else {
      x.style.opacity = '0';
   }
}
```

Some links for References :
[Opacity](https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_opacity.asp)
[Transition](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)